# How do I give texture to a liquid?

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation

I want to make my textured objects to turn into a liquid. 
Here is an example with solar panel:
[image]

But I can't get the texture to mix like it was liquid:
[image]

No one of the texture coordinate outputs work right and the uv one just makes the liquid white. 
Anyone knows how I can make it can be made so it looks like the solar panel just turned into liquid and started to mix together?

Comment: "solar panel just turned into liquid and started to mix together" is very hard to imagine. Would you have an example of that? a link to a picture or video?

Comment: Probably not, haven't seen it before. Just imagine what would happen if solar panel suddenly became liquid with the same colours. Little bit surreal but yeah.

Comment: I dont think you'll be able to achieve this with simple coordinate mapping, for it to "mix together", each individual colored bit of the object would need to be simulated separately so that the colors would move around and mix.

Comment: Anyone knows if this is even possible with the mantaflow we have now? All the tutorials on making objects melt were made for objects without textures so idk if this is even possible.